# Xamarin Cross Platform Dual Slider

Tags: ios, xamarin, slider, controls, rangeslider

Has anyone heard about a double sided Slider for Xamarin Forms?  I am looking but can't seem to find one.  The native Xamarin Forms Slider is very nice looking but it only supports 1 marker.  I am looking for a Slider with two markers one on each side.

Has anyone heard of this or know how to extend a Xamarin Control to add similar functionality.

Any help would be appreciated in this matter.

I have found the Range Slider here

https://components.xamarin.com/view/rangeslider

Unfortanately the control has an iOS 4 look and can't be stylized or updated visually from what Ive read.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you please post?

Comment: No, I ended up using two sliders on two different lines, to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there really isnt anything native, you can try to extend the native slider or stack two sliders beside each other to give the desired effect.

Also you can check out

https://components.xamarin.com/view/rangeslider

but it looks pretty old and isnt easily extendable.

Lets go Xamarin give us a Dual Slider!!!  Or elseeee??!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for iOS. Hope it helps!

```
public class UIRangeSlider : UIControl
{
    public nfloat MinValue;
    public nfloat MaxValue;
    public nfloat MinRange;
    public nfloat SelectedMinValue;
    public nfloat SelectedMaxValue;
    public Action<UIRangeSlider> ThumbChanged;

    private UIImageView minThumb, maxThumb, track, trackBackground;
    nfloat padding = 15.0f;
    bool maxThumbOn = false;
    bool minThumbOn = false;
    nfloat distanceFromCenter;

    public UIRangeSlider(CGRect frame)
        : base(frame)
    {
        trackBackground = new UIImageView(Resources.SliderTrackBackground.StretchableImage(1, 1));
        trackBackground.Center = Center;
        AddSubview(trackBackground);

        track = new UIImageView(Resources.SliderTrackGreen);
        track.Center = Center;
        AddSubview(track);

        minThumb = new UIImageView(Resources.SliderHandle, Resources.SliderHandle);
        minThumb.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Size.Height, Frame.Size.Height);
        minThumb.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
        AddSubview(minThumb);

        maxThumb = new UIImageView(Resources.SliderHandle, Resources.SliderHandle);
        maxThumb.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Size.Height, Frame.Size.Height);
        maxThumb.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
        AddSubview(maxThumb);
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        minThumb.Center = new CGPoint(XForValue(SelectedMinValue), Center.Y - Frame.Top);
        maxThumb.Center = new CGPoint(XForValue(SelectedMaxValue), Center.Y - Frame.Top);

        // minThumb.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        // minThumb.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;

        // maxThumb.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        // maxThumb.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;

        UpdateTrackHighlight();
    }

    private nfloat XForValue(nfloat val)
    {
        return (Frame.Size.Width - (padding * 2)) * ((val - MinValue) / (MaxValue - MinValue)) + padding;
    }

    private nfloat ValueForX(nfloat x)
    {
        return MinValue + (x - padding) / (Frame.Size.Width - (padding * 2)) * (MaxValue - MinValue);
    }

    public override bool ContinueTracking(UITouch uitouch, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        if (!minThumbOn && !maxThumbOn)
            return true;

        var touchPoint = uitouch.LocationInView(this);
        if (minThumbOn)
        {
            var xValue = (nfloat)Math.Max(XForValue(MinValue), Math.Min(touchPoint.X - distanceFromCenter, XForValue(SelectedMaxValue - MinRange)));
            var yValue = minThumb.Center.Y - Frame.Top;
            minThumb.Center = new CGPoint(xValue, yValue);
            SelectedMinValue = ValueForX(minThumb.Center.X);
        }

        if (maxThumbOn)
        {
            var xValue = (nfloat) Math.Min(XForValue(MaxValue), Math.Max(touchPoint.X - distanceFromCenter, XForValue(SelectedMinValue + MinRange)));
            var yValue = maxThumb.Center.Y - Frame.Top;
            maxThumb.Center = new CGPoint(xValue, yValue);
            SelectedMaxValue = ValueForX(maxThumb.Center.X);
        }

        UpdateTrackHighlight();
        this.SetNeedsLayout();

        if (ThumbChanged != null)
            ThumbChanged(this);

        return true;
    }

    public override bool BeginTracking(UITouch uitouch, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        var touchPoint = uitouch.LocationInView(this);

        if (minThumb.Frame.Contains(touchPoint))
        {
            minThumbOn = true;
            distanceFromCenter = touchPoint.X - minThumb.Center.X;
        }
        else if (maxThumb.Frame.Contains(touchPoint))
        {
            maxThumbOn = true;
            distanceFromCenter = touchPoint.X - maxThumb.Center.X;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override void EndTracking(UITouch uitouch, UIEvent uievent)
    {
        minThumbOn = false;
        maxThumbOn = false;
    }

    private void UpdateTrackHighlight()
    {
        track.Frame = new CGRect(minThumb.Center.X, 
            maxThumb.Center.Y - (track.Frame.Height / 2),
            maxThumb.Center.X - minThumb.Center.X,
            track.Frame.Size.Height);

        // track.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        // track.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;

        trackBackground.Frame = new CGRect(1, 
            maxThumb.Center.Y - (trackBackground.Frame.Height / 2),
            Frame.Width-2, trackBackground.Frame.Size.Height);

        // trackBackground.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
        // trackBackground.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  I will check this out.  For my current implementation I just use two separate sliders for Min and Max, since I couldn't find an acceptable solution for the dual slider.